# Is there a polynomial, in terms of $x^4$ and $x$, whose graph is not below the graph of the function $y=x^3$

Tags: polynomials

I tried several coefficients before $x^4$ and $x$, but I didn't get it unless adding a constant term.

Comment: May be your problem means a x^4 + b x or simply x^4 + a x

Comment: What do u mean by always above? What can we do when $x\to +\infty$?

Comment: I mean for every $x$, the polynomial's value at that $x$ is greater than $x^3$.

Answer (score 2):

No, since in the interval $[0,1]$, the $x$ term will be the dominant one, we know that for the hypothesis to be true, $nx>1$, $n \in R$.Hence, We need $x>1/n$ $\forall x \in [0,1]$ and, we can't have that for all $x \in [0,1]$ because any positive number $'k'$, we will have $\infty$ positive numbers in $ [0,1]$ such that they are $ < k$.

Or

To Prove:

$ax^4-x^3+cx>=0$ for all $x \in R$,now we know that at $x=0$ the function is 0 and since the derivative of the function at $0$ isn't $0$, it won't have an inflexion point, hence will change sign at $x=0$, hence proved.

Answer (score 1):

If your function is only in terms of $x^4$ and $x$, then the answer is no, because your function will equal $0$ at $x=0$, meaning that it will coincide with $y = x^3$ there.

Answer (score 1):

$ax^4+bx\geqslant x^3\iff$ $P(x)=ax^4-x^3+bx\geqslant0$. But for $x=0$ we already have $P(x)=0$, and since $P(x)$ is not allowed to be negative, this means that $x=0$ must be a minimum of $P(x)$. But local extremes are to be found among the roots of the derivative, which in our case is $4ax^3$$-3x^2$$+b$ which does not allow $x=0$ as a root, unless *b* itself is also $0$, in which case the term in *x* vanishes, thus breaking the rules laid out in the enunciation of the problem. If however *b* **is** allowed to be $0$, then the other two roots are both $\displaystyle\frac3{4a}$ , in which case we must have $P\left(\frac3{4a}\right)\geqslant0$, and all that's left is to solve for *a*, with the mention that when multiplying both sides of an inequality with a negative number, the symbol must be reversed, so there will have to be a discussion as to the sign of *a*.

Answer (score 0):

it's doable if you can use $x^4$ as a term in the polynomial. look at $(x^4)^3 + x^4$ and work from there.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can not. Lets study the function $x^4+x-x^3$ close to zero, that is

$$ x^4+x-x^3 \sim x.$$

Now, you can see that the function always take negative values if we are in the neighbourhood $(-\delta, 0),\quad \delta >0$.

**Note:** You can make the same analysis for the general function $ax^4+bx-x^3$.